# Are uploaded files on an SSL site encrpyted?

Tags: html, ssl, security

Using a form inside a HTML such that the input is:

```
<input id="afile" type="file" accept="*.csv" name="afile">
```

And sent via javascript like:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#afile').change(onChange);
  });

  function onChange() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("afile", file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload/handle_upload.php5', true);
    xhr.send(fd);
  }
```

I watch the request data in the Net panel of Firebug and Live HTTP headers but all data appears in plaintext (I am assuming that they are showing pre-encrpytion).

Is the file encrypted before transfer? If so, when does the file become encrypted?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19681/2435) asked recently on Security.SE. Essentially, the SSL/TLS layer is under the HTTP layer, which is what the web debugging tools show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a HTTPS connection, it will be encrypted before leaving the browser. The Net Panel inside of the browser will probably show it decrypted for your convenience. If you used a network sniffer, you should be able to verify that the connection is secure.

> Is the file encrypted before transfer?

The file per se is not encrypted, but the complete HTTP request is (and the file is in there).